# Find maximum product using recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, divide-and-conquer

There's a question I saw and I'm wondering if it's possible to solve it using recursion.  It goes as follow:

Write an algorithm that, when given an array of input, finds the maximum product from those inputs.  For example:

```
Input: [1, 2, 3]
Output: 6 (1*2*3)
```

```
Input: [-1, 1, 2, 3]
Output: 6 (1*2*3)
```

```
Input: [-2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
Output: 12 (-2*-1*1*2*3)
```

I'm trying to find a way of using recursion to solve it, but the algorithm I tried doesn't work.  My algorithm, written in Java is as follow

```
Integer[] array;
public int maximumProduct(int[] nums) {
   array=new Integer[nums.length];
   return multiply(nums, 0);
}

public int multiply(int[] nums, int i){
    if (array[i]!=null){
        return array[i];
    }
    if (i==(nums.length-1)){
        return nums[i];
    }
    int returnval=Math.max(nums[i]*multiply(nums, i+1), multiply(nums, i+1));
    array[i]=returnval;
    return returnval;

}
```

The problem with this algorithm is that it doesn't work well if there's an even number of negative numbers.  For example, if nums[0]=-2, nums[1]=-1 and nums[2]=1, then multiply(nums, 1) will always return 1 instead of -1, and thus it will always see 1 as bigger than 1*-2 at multiply(nums, 0).  I'm not sure how to solve this problem, however.  Is there any way of solving this using recursion or dynamic programming?

Comment: If you're restricted to int, count number of negative integers. If odd, drop smallest negative integer, else multiply all others for largest product. Remove any zeros first. Don't need recursion.

Comment: Does it have to be recursion or double for loop is okay too?

Comment: I'm hoping to use recursion, just because I'm trying to improve my skills with recursion, which has always been a weak point for me.

Answer (score 1):

**What is the maximum product of integers?**

To obtain the maximum sum, you will want to multiply all the positive integers with the product of the largest negative integers, with the number of negative integers included in the product being even to obtain a positive final result.

**In an algorithm for a single traversal**

I am going to treat the positive integers and the negative integers in the input separately. You will want to keep a running product of positive integers, a running product of negative integers and the largest negative integer (ie. the negative integer with the smallest absolute value) found so far. 
Let us ignore the edge cases where the final answer is <= 0. That can be handled easily.

```
//Initialization
int [] nums // Input
int posProduct = 1;
int negProduct = 1;
int smallestNeg = 1;

//Input Traversal
for (int i : nums) {
  if ( i == 0 ) {
    // ignore
  } else if ( i < 0 ) {
    if (smallestNeg == 1) {
      smallestNeg = i;
    } else if ( i > smallestNeg ) {
      negProduct *= smallestNeg; //Integrate the old smallest into the running product
      smallestNeg = i;           // i is the new smallest
    } else {
      negProduct *= i;
    }
  } else {
    // i is strictly positive
    posProduct *= i;
  }
}

//Result Computation
int result = posProduct;
if ( negProduct < 0 ) {
  // The running product of negative number numbers is negative
  // We use the smallestNeg to turn it back up to a positive product
  result *= smallestNeg;
  result *= negProduct;
} else {
  result *= negProduct
}
```

edit: **In a recursive traversal**

I personally find that writing the array traversal in a recursive manner to be clumsy but it can be done. 
For the beauty of the exercise and to actually answer the question of the OP, here is how I would do it.

```
public class RecursiveSolver {
  public static int findMaxProduct (int [] nums) {
    return recursiveArrayTraversal(1, 1, 1, nums, 0); 
  }

  private static int recursiveArrayTraversal(int posProduct, int negProduct, 
      int smallestNeg, int [] nums, int index) {
    if (index == nums.length) {
      // End of the recursion, we traversed the whole array
      posProduct *= negProduct;
      if (posProduct < 0) {
        posProduct *= smallestNeg;
      }
      return posProduct;
    }

    // Processing the "index" element of the array
    int i = nums[index];
    if ( i == 0 ) {
      // ignore
    } else if ( i < 0 ) {
      if (smallestNeg == 1) {
        smallestNeg = i;
      } else if ( i > smallestNeg ) {
        negProduct *= smallestNeg; 
        smallestNeg = i;
      } else {
        negProduct *= i;
      }
    } else {
      // i is strictly positive
      posProduct *= i;
    }

    //Recursive call here! 
    //Notice the index+1 for the index parameter which carries the progress 
    //in the array traversal
    return recursiveArrayTraversal(posProduct, negProduct, 
      smallestNeg, nums, index+1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one non-zero element in the array, and it happens to be a negative number, then then answer is either 0, if there is a 0 present in the input, or if the array contains only that single negative element, the answer is that element itself.

In all other cases, the final answer is going to be positive.

We first make a linear scan to find the number of negative integers. If this number is even, then the answer is the product of all the non-zero elements. If there are an odd number of negative elements, we need to leave out one negative element from the answer, so that the answer is positive. As we want the maximum possible answer, the number we want to leave out should have as small an absolute value as possible. So among all the negative numbers, find the one with the minimum absolute value, and find the product of the remaining non-zero elements, which should be the answer.

All this requires only two linear scans of the array, and hence runs in O(n) time.

Comment: I had taken OP's " I'm not sure how to solve this problem" to mean that they couldn't solve the whole problem, but upon second reading I guess what they are referring to is the particular issue that they found in the recursive solution. My bad.

Should I delete this answer? Not sure of the protocol.

Comment: Nope.  Just keep it.  Someone will find it useful.

Comment: If you need to use recursion, you will need two functions, one to find the minimum, and one to find the maximum or the remaining elements.   First, get it working without any optimizations, such as less than one, negative, etc., call both minimum and maximum, and see if multiplying by min and max, which of the four gives the largest value.  Do similar (but opposite) for the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Linear version

```
        List<Integer> vals = new ArrayList<>(List.of(5,1,-2,1,2,3,-4,-1));

        int prod = 0;
        int min = 1;
        for (int v : vals) {
            if (v == 0) {
                // ignore zero values
                continue;
            }
            if (prod == 0) {
                prod = 1;
            }
            prod *= v;
            // compute min to be the largest negative value in the list.
            if (v < 0 && min < Math.abs(v)) {
                min = v;
            }
        }
        if (prod < 0) {
            prod /= min;
        }

        System.out.println("Maximum product = " + prod);
    }
```

Recursive version

```
        int prod = prod(vals, new int[] {0} , vals.size());
        System.out.println("Maximum product = " + prod);

    public static int prod(List<Integer> vals, int[]min, int size) {
        int prod = 0;
        if(vals.size() > 0) {
            int t = vals.get(0);
             if (t < 0 && min[0] < Math.abs(t)) {
                    min[0] = t;
             }
             prod = prod(vals.subList(1,vals.size()), min, vals.size());
        }
        if (vals.isEmpty() || vals.get(0) == 0) {
            return prod;
        }

        if (prod == 0) {
           prod = 1;
        }
        prod *= t;

        if (vals.size() == size && prod < 0) {
            prod/=min[0];
        }
        return prod;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution - leaving it open for optimization and to figure out the runtime. This is a general purpose solution that finds the products of **all the combinations** of integers in a list. Of course, there is a O(n) solution but I present this solution as well.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MaxProd {

    int[] input = {1, 2, 3};

    // int[] input = {-2, -1, 1, 2, 3};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MaxProd m = new MaxProd();
        List<Integer> ll =  m.max(0);
        for (int i : ll) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        ll.sort((x,y) -> Integer.compare(x, y));
        System.out.println("The max: " + ll.get(ll.size() -1 ));

    }

    private List<Integer> max(int index) {
        if (index < input.length){
            List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Integer> retList = max(index + 1);

            for (int j : retList){
                l.add(input[index] * j);
            }
            l.add(input[index]);
            l.addAll(retList);
            return l;
        }
        else return new ArrayList<>();

    }
}
```

it prints:

```
6
2
3
1
6
2
3
The max: 6
```

If the requirements are constrained (as in this case) then one can get by without the need for generating all combinations resulting in a linear solution. Also, I'm sorting at the end. Note: you could easily get the result with a single pass on the returned list to find the maximum product as specified in other answers.

Comment: This looks to use O(n^2log(n)) time (or O(n^2) if you don't sort), whereas there's an O(n) solution.

Comment: @PaulHankin: is it not 2^n?

Comment: You don't need to sort to get the product  on a single pass.

Comment: @WJS: you are right. This is a general purpose solution that deals with all the combinations. I have mentioned it. I can make it more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

First, break the array in subproblems always you find a 0 in the list:

```
 1 -2  4 -1  8  0  4  1  0 -3 -4  0  1  3 -5
|_____________|   |____|   |____|   |_______|
       p1           p2       p3         p4
```

Then, for each problem `pi`, count how many negative numbers are there.

If `pi` has an even number of negatives (or no negatives at all), the answer of `pi` is the product of all its elements.

If `pi` has only 1 negative number (say `n`), the answer will be the maximum between the product of all the elements in `n`'s right and the product of all elements in `n`'s left.

If `pi` has an odd number (bigger than only 1) of negative numbers, call the index of the leftmost negative number `l` and the index of the rightmost negative number `r`. Supposing `pi` has `n` elements, the answer will be:

```
max(
    pi[  0  ] * pi[  1  ] * ... * pi[r - 1],
    pi[l + 1] * pi[l + 2] * ... * pi[  n  ]
)
```

Knowing that, it's easy to write a recursion for each step of the solution of this problem: a recursion to divide problems at zeros, another to count negatives and another to find answers, in O(n).